# add image to my layout with size proportional to dimension of screen android

Tags: android, imageview

In my application i have an image that should have 25% width and height of screen.
I hope this is clear. This is what i'm already tried but doesn't work. Thank you.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/fish"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
```

Comment: Use CENTER_INSIDE for the image to stay inside or CENTER_CROP for the scaleType. Those keep the proportions of the image.

Comment: Try to put complete XML or the parent of this ImageView. If the parent of this ImageView is Vertical LinearLayout then your ImageView's height must be "0dp" to take the exact weight that you assign to this ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Just use this with Linear Layout

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">




    <ImageView 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="25"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want my image have height and width 25% of my screen not only height

Comment: @SidaouiMejdi-I have edited some new thing just check and tell me it is useful for u ...

Comment: @SidaouiMejdi-and set image in center just use this code in <ImagView     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

Comment: i get this warnning "Use a layout_width of 0dip instead of wrap_content for better performance"

Comment: @SidaouiMejdi-ok its fine u just write android:layout_height="0dip" and hope rest of code is useful for u..

Comment: sorry it's not working, the resize is always in one direction

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, your need is to relate your image view dimension with the device screen.

Here is it.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
      int w= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
   Log.d("Nzm", ""+w);
    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
   img.setWidth((int)(w/4));// to set 25%
}
```

Also, make sure inside layout, the parent width is fillparent, and set the id for imageview.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```